# configure FQDN site for iisexpress using appcmd

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express, appcmd

I want to be able to configure my applicationhost.config to include a FQDN for my site. I have a batch file to set this up as visual studio complains about it when it loads.

[This article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services#FQDN) says that running

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /+"[name='WebApplication1'].bindings.[protocol='http',bindingInformation='*:80:www.wingtiptoys.com']" /commit:apphost
```

should add the correct entry (im assuming to the gloabl apphost), however i get the following error when I run it:

> ERROR ( message:Cannot find requested collection element. )

This is not a super helpful error message.

**How can I setup a FQDN url for IIS Express from the commandline?**

Comment: You have to use the appcmd under IIS Express installation folder.

Comment: @lexli Im using it in %programfiles%\iis express like it says in the article. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Which version of IIS Express then? And what full path is the config file you want to change?

Comment: Hi. Did you mange to resolve your issue?